# with in C, access variable in structure

Tags: c, struct

I have the following code, which is not how to implement in C, (if it has one, the keyword with.On the other hand because the program does not access the data type structure, it should not give an error because the variables partial_n2, final_n2, name2 are defined in the struct.

The program has to store in an array of records the names of the students, their partial and final grades. Find the average grade and show a message of SUIT if the student exceeds or equals the grade of 5 or NOT SUIT if it is not enough. Do it for a number of 5 students.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
//PROGRAM EJER009
#define numstudents 5

typedef struct notas{
    char name2[20];
    float partial_n2, final_n2;
}tnotas;

tnotas notas[numstudents];

tnotas clase;
char name[20];
float partial_n, final_n, n_media;
int i;

int main(){
    for (i = 0; i <= numstudents;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the student's name% d: ",i);
        scanf("%s",name);
        printf("Enter your partial note: ");
        scanf("%f",&partial_n);
        printf("Enter your final note: ");
        scanf("%f",&final_n);
        printf("\n");
        with (clase[i])
        {
            partial_n2 = partial_n;
            final_n2 = final_n;
            name2 = name;
        }
    }

    printf("cls");

    printf("NAME\tPartial\tFinal\tMedia\tQUALIFICATION\n");

    for (i = 1; i<=numstudents;i++){
    with clase[i]
    {
    n_media = (partial_n2 + final_n2) / 2;
    printf("%d %d %d",name2,partial_n2,final_n2);
    system("color 14"); printf("%lf",n_media);
    if (n_media >= 5)
    {
        system("color 11");
        printf("SUITABLE :-)");
    }
    else
    {
        system("color 1");
        printf("NOT SUITABLE :-(");
    }
    system("color 7");
    }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question?

Comment: It is explained above

Comment: Change ```for (i = 1; i <= numstudents;i++)``` to ```for (i = 0; i < numstudents;i++)```. C uses zero indexing.

Comment: *"It is explained above"* - I'm afraid it's not. Be explicit please, don't leave things to interpretation.

Comment: Where is ```with``` defined? You probably want to access a member by using ```clase[i].partial_n2 = ...```.

Comment: Your loop still ends beyond the number of elements. ```i <= numstudents``` will read beyond the length of the array. Use ```i < numstudents```.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a value of a member by:

```
float f;
f = notas[0].partial_n2;
```

You can write a value of a member by:

```
notas[0].partial_n2 = 10.3;
```